# How to avoid conflict in two header file c++

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I am using two lib jsoncpp and imap (lib c-client).

json cpp have write function . 
but in imap lib they have some macro `#define write safe_write`
which is overriding some macro from jsoncpp . 
I am not able to use both library at same time. 
how can I avoid this conflict ?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but perhaps `#include` them in namespaces?

Comment: @Maxpm sir can you please give one example ?

Comment: @Maxpm: macros don't care about namespaces. That's one of the reasons they're evil :)

Comment: Switch to another IMAP library, no joke. Library developer who leaves `#define write safe_write` in a public header file needs to be... punished... severely... There's `write` function in POSIX even: http://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't use write macro from imap:

```
#include "imap.h"
#undef write
#include "jsoncpp.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to proceed is to encapsulate the offending header (here `imap`) in a header that'll behave "better".

Note that this `#define` is actually a lazy man inline function. You need to identify all the declarations of `safe_write` and provide appropriate overloads, in the same namespaces.

```
// my_imap.h
#include "imap.h"
#undef write

inline void write(FILE* file, char* content, size_t size) {
  safe_write(file, content, size);
}

// ...
```

Then include `my_imap.h` instead of `imap.h`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have access to the headers and you are using a lib or dll, you should be able to `#undef` it, so long as you don't use the macro.